# S3: "Redirect all requests to another host name" over HTTPS

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an S3 bucket and enabled "Redirect all requests to another host name" under "Static Website Hosting".

This works and when I visit http://www.XXXX.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com, I am redirected to my end destination.

If however, I try to access the same URL over HTTPS: https://www.XXXX.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com, the connection times out.

Is it possible to specify an SSL certificate to use so that the redirect can handle HTTPS traffic?

Comment: Same as [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44887910/https-on-s3-static-website-gets-stuck/44889988#44889988) Just a slightly more streamlined answer.

Answer (score 0):

With S3 by itself, no, it isn't possible.  The web site endpoints don't speak SSL at all, and the REST endpoints don't handle redirects or allow any cert other than the `*.s3(-region).amazonaws.com` cert.

However, you can do it with CloudFront and S3 combined, if your clients support SNI.

Create a CloudFront distribution, configured with your hostname and SSL certificate, but don't use an "S3 Origin."  Use a "custom origin" and that origin is your S3 web site endpoint hostname, with all requests forwarded to the origin using http (even though it's https on the front end).

If you are not familiar with CloudFront, this probably sounds a little convoluted, but I use it for exactly this purpose (among others).

Requests hit CloudFront, which allows you to use your own SSL cert... and then CloudFront forwards the request to S3, which returns the redirect, which CloudFront will cache and return to the requester (as well as to future requesters hitting the same CloudFront edge location).

The cost for this extra layer is negligible and you should not see any meaningful change in performance (if anything, there's potential for a slight speed improvement).