# https on S3 static website gets stuck

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, curl, amazon-s3

I've created an S3 bucket and made it a static website.

If I try a redirect (e.g. to Google) it works fine for HTTP. E.g.

`curl -I  http://test-s3-redirect.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

but for HTTPS it just hangs eventually returning `curl: (7) Failed to connect to test-s3-redirect.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com port 443: Operation timed out`
. E.g.

`curl -I  https://test-s3-redirect.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

The options I chose in `AWS > S3 > Static website hosting` were:

- Redirect requests
- Target bucket or domain: www.google.com
- Protocol: https

Any idea why?

Answer (score 5):

The redirect protocol (in this case HTTPS) only defines the target protocol for your redirect. Your bucket is still not available with a HTTPS endpoint.

> Website Endpoint: Does not support SSL connections.

[Key Differences Between the Amazon Website and the REST API Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteEndpoints.html)

If you need SSL support, you put a cloudfront distribution up front.

Comment: This was a very useful answer.  Thank you.  It was still a lot of work to correctly create the Cloudfront distribution, though.